# How to know which default route is default and will be excute in MVC 4 of this code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a RouteConfig.cs file, and i don't know which will be excute, please tell me, and explain to me.

It's about **asp.net MVC4**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            #region Special Page
            // Admin Router
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "Admin/",
                defaults: new { area = "Admin", controller = "dashboard", action = "index" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Error Page, NotFound And UnderConstruction
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ErrorsLang",
                url: "{culture}/Errors/{action}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Errors", action = "NotFound" },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Errors",
                url: "Errors/{action}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Errors", action = "NotFound" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Home
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Home",
            //    url: "{culture}/",
            //    defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Home", action = "Index", type = "", slug = "" },
            //    namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            //);

            // Common
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Common",
                url: "Common/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Common
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Widget",
                url: "Widget/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Widget", action = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Login
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LoginPanel",
                url: "account/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Login
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AccountLang",
                url: "{culture}/account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // Contact
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ContactLang",
                url: "{culture}/Contact/{add}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Contact", add = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Contact",
                url: "Contact/{add}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Contact",add=UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );


            // Search
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SearchLang",
                url: "{culture}/Search/",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Search" },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Search",
                url: "Search/",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Search" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            // cart
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ShoppingCartLang",
                url: "{culture}/ShoppingCart/",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Index", type = "", slug = "" },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ShoppingCart",
                url: "ShoppingCart/",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Index", type = "", slug = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );
            #endregion

            // Slug
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Slug",
            //    url: "{culture}/{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}/{slug4}",
            //    defaults: new { culture = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Content", action = "Slug", slug1 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug2 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug3 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug4 = UrlParameter.Optional },
            //    namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            //);

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SlugLang",
                url: "{culture}/{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}/{slug4}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Slug", slug1 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug2 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug3 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug4 = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = "[a-z]{2}" },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Slug",
                url: "{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}/{slug4}",
                defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Content", action = "Slug", slug1 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug2 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug3 = UrlParameter.Optional, slug4 = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "PixelCMS.Controllers" }
            );
```

`

And i wonder that will  RouteConfig file all the links of site?
i am a newbie about MVC4, and route file and

```
@HTML.Action("LoadURL","Common",new {...})
@Html.Action().
```

command is correspond of Routeconfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry writing you back in reply instead of writing in comment. ( don't have enough reputation to write back in comment)

Routes work in the order they are defined, in your case you have defined multiple routes and when ever you make any request it will start from top and traverse to the bottom, first one matched with the rule will get hit.

And in most of the cases you don't need these many route sections, only few logical one can help you. For an instance

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This will try to match url with controller name and then see if that controller has any action and in this case id is optional.

Comment: could you specify what will be called when i make a request to my browser is http://localhost:xxxxx/    ?

Comment: I guess you will get an HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden kind of error. But if you write like  localhost:xxxxx/ShoppingCart or something like this then you will get redirected to corresponding controller and action.